# CrudRepository auto update other fields in custom update

Tags: java, spring, service, repository, crud-repository

I'm using CrudRepository, Mysql in my Spring boot application. I have class Account like below

```
@Entity
@Table(name="account")
public class Account {

 @Column(name="account_id")
 @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private long accountId;

 @Column(name="username", unique = true)
 private String username;

 @Column(name="email", unique = true)
 private String email;

 @Column(name="password")
 private String password;

 @Column(name="fname")
 private String fname;

 @Column(name="lname")
 private String lname;

 @Column(name="birth_date")
 @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
 private Date birth_date;
```

My AccountController takes some parameters and updates instance of class Account

```
@PutMapping("/update/{username}")
@ResponseBody
public Boolean updateAccount(@PathVariable String username,
                                 @RequestParam(name="email",required = false) String email,
                                 @RequestParam(name="lname",required = false) String  lname,
                                 @RequestParam(name="fname",required = false) String fname,
                                 @RequestParam(name="birth_date",required = false) String birth_date,
                                 @RequestParam(name="password",required = false) String password){
    Account account = accountService.getAccountByUsername(username);
    if (email!= null) account.setEmail(email);
    if (lname!= null) account.setLname(lname);
    if (fname!= null) account.setFname(fname);
    if (password!= null) account.setPassword(password);
    if (birth_date!= null) {
        //   DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
        System.out.println("Account Controller");
        accountService.updateBirthDate(account, birth_date);
    }

    if (!accountService.checkAccountExistByEmail(email)) {
       accountService.updateAccount(account);
       return true;
    }else return false;
}
```

my AccountService method to update birth_date is something like this

```
public void updateBirthDate(Account account, String date){
    System.out.println("Account Service");
    accountRepository.updateBD(date, account.getId());
}
```

And my custom repository

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "UPDATE account SET birth_date =:date WHERE account_id =:id",
       nativeQuery = true)
void updateBD(@Param("date") String date, @Param("id") Long id);
```

Everything seems work fine. You can see my AccountController, i called method **updateBirthday** before **checkExistEmail**. But when the first time i updated Account with full parameters, the method **updateBD** in Repository auto save updated account with other fields like email, lname, fname... so it leads to problem that **email** field auto update before actually called.
Below is logs file
[image]

How can i update only birth_date without update other fields.

Comment: You should understand how JPA works. If you issue a query it will first flush the dirty state to the database, so that the data in the database is consistent with the data in JPA. But why on earth are you using a query instead of just setting the birthday on the entity?

Comment: @M.Deinum i create db first, then create data class. Before this, i got problem with insert Date to created database, so i made it custom. I forgot about set up the birthday on the entity. Following your answer, are there any solutions to block flushing the dirty state?

Comment: You can change the flush mode to manual, however this means that you need to flush **everything** yourself and that a transaction commit doesnt' automatically flush changes. So yes you can but this will have a severe impact on your whole application!. The easiest is to map the field to your entity and just set it.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are some unconventional things I see in the code, But, immediate solution to your problem would be:

```
@PutMapping("/update/{username}")
@ResponseBody
public Boolean updateAccount(@PathVariable String username,
                                 @RequestParam(name="email",required = false) String email,
                                 @RequestParam(name="lname",required = false) String  lname,
                                 @RequestParam(name="fname",required = false) String fname,
                                 @RequestParam(name="birth_date",required = false) String birth_date,
                                 @RequestParam(name="password",required = false) String password){
    Account account = accountService.getAccountByUsername(username);
    if (birth_date!= null) {
        //   DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
        System.out.println("Account Controller");
        accountService.updateBirthDate(account, birth_date);
    }

    if (email!= null) account.setEmail(email);
    if (lname!= null) account.setLname(lname);
    if (fname!= null) account.setFname(fname);
    if (password!= null) account.setPassword(password);
    if (!accountService.checkAccountExistByEmail(email)) {
       accountService.updateAccount(account);
       return true;
    }else return false;
}
```